# Combined null and value check

Tags: c#, null, resharper, evaluation

This code works fine:

```
policy.ProviderID > 0 ? RefDataSources.LegalBodies.GetDisplayName(policy.ProviderID.Value) : null
```

but Resharper is complaining that `policy.ProviderID.Value` needs to be `null` checked (to prevent an `InvalidOperationException`).

As far as I am aware the condition will only evaluate to true for a non-null value which is  greater than `0` and therefore no further check is required.

Should I be logging this as a bug with JetBrains?
Or have I misunderstood something.

Comment: What is the type of policy.ProviderID?

Comment: @Matt Apparently `int?`

Comment: @IvanStoev, how did you come to that conclusion? I can't see anything to would confirm it's of that type.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Well it looks like it's a nullable value type of some numeric type in order for it to be compared with 0. I agree that it would be good to know for sure, but I think it's a reasonable guess for now.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I believe because of `ProviderId.Value`, nullable types have a `.Value` property

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko What else it could be that compiles fine, but bothers ReSharper? Well, let say it apparently (to me) is `Nullable<T>` os some numeric type as Jon mentioned.

Comment: It could be of any type that provides an overridden implementation of the greater-than operator and a property called Value. No reason to assume it's necessarily a Nullable<T>, but this is a digression.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I was playing devil advocate :) I agree int? is mostly likely the type, I was just pointing out that there are other possibilities.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko +1 for devil advocate - LOL. You are right of course, I was just thinking the question about the type is irrelevant to the OP issue. Just IMO.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it originally. It is indeed int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect R# is complaining because it doesn't know that `policy.ProviderID` will return the same value on both evaluations. Consider:

```
private readonly int? providerId;

public int? EvilProviderId => DateTime.UtcNow.Second == 0 ? null : providerId;
```

Now consider your code - the *condition* could be true because the first call is executed on second 59... but then the clock ticks before the second call, which would then return null, causing a `NullReferenceException`.

If that *is* why R# is complaining, just extract a local variable:

```
int? providerId = policy.ProviderId;
// Use providerId in both cases in your expression
```

Comment: I get the same behavior locally. However, changing it to `var t = p.ProviderID.HasValue ? (int?)p.ProviderID.Value : null;` removes the warning, but is still vulnerable to the situation you outlined. It's possibly due to R# not differentiating `int?` from any other `Nullable<T>` where `T` might have the operators overloaded. Interesting, nevertheless

Comment: Further, your fix for extracting the local variable does in fact remove the warning too.

Comment: I vaguely thought of that but if the "> 0" check is replaced (or supplemented) with "!= null" then Resharper removes the warning, so I thought it must be something else.

Comment: @SimonHewitt: I suspect the heuristics are quite fiddly... I would suggest just going with the "extract local variable" version anyway.

Comment: So I guess Resharper is only concerned with null checks but is not treating '>0' as one - is that an inconsistency worth reporting to them?
(The line I quoted is part of another ternary operator and so best left as-is in this case but I'll remember the local variable option - thanks)
[Edit: Jon is so quick! This comment was meant to be a continuation of my last one]

Comment: @SimonHewitt: I'd definitely report it, because it sounds like it *does* treat `> 0` as a nullity check in some cases... but possibly not as strongly.

Comment: I must have used better keywords on the Resharper site this time because I found the issue is already reported at [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-363592#tab=Comments). Problem is still there in v10 which I just installed so have given it a bump.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
(policy != null && policy.ProviderID.HasValue &&  policy.ProviderID. Value > 0) ? RefDataSources.LegalBodies.GetDisplayName(policy.ProviderID.Value) : null
```

Comment: Whaw, and all that just to make ReSharper happy? The OP code is perfectly correct if the property is not mutating between the calls, but if it does, your code snippet will also not work.